# How to wire html template to twig extension? (Mainly `Twig\Error\SyntaxError: Unknown filter Error`)

Tags: craft3, php, yii

I am going to use a Twig filter function by using Twig extension in my HTML file.

I followed this guide.

https://cameronspear.com/craft-cms-twig-filter-extension/

But when I run

```
<p>{{ 123 | wordItUp }}</p>
```

It throws this error

> Twig\Error\SyntaxError: Unknown "wordItUp" filter. in /var/www/craft/templates/loggedin.html:1`

My HTML where I want to use the Twig filter function looks like this:

```
<div>{{ 'developer' | saveToken }}</div>
{{ redirect "/portfolio?token={ 'username' | saveToken }" }}`
```

I think it has some additional settings between HTML and Twig extension?
Not sure right now.

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/277183/twig-error-uknown-image-style-filter-but-the-filter-isnt-missing

After research I found the similar issue to this issue.
But it's in Drupal, I am really not sure, please elaborate on this, thanks!